# Random User Interaction generator - Akka actors

Tags: random, akka, actor

I am now starting to learn the actor programming model. For practice I'm planning to use the Akka actors to generate random user interactions.

For starters I'm thinking of implementing a simple state machine like: user login, then perform 0 or more actions and then go to a final state (logout).

[image]

I'm thinking of the following actor hierarchy. The `OrchestratorActor` receives a config of the traffic specs it should generate and then delegates to one of the actors involved in the start states. Then, for each "level" the actors delegate to a random actor from the layer beneath.

[image]

Questions:

1. What do you think of the actor hierarchy proposed?
2. I'm going to use the scheduler to delay the "actions". The `OrchestratorActor` must ensure the traffic it generates matches the given conditions (e.g. 80% legit, 20% fraudulent traffic or something like that). How can I do that? Splitting the traffic into chunks (10 minute) and making sure that the conditions are met for the current chunk?

Thank you in advance!
I don't need code, only ideas no matter how smart/crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I have two suggestions:

- check the [Finite State Machine](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/fsm.html) model. you can move between states (login, action, logout) using a random function.
- alternatively, use the become() technique to change the receive behavior of your actor and send it a message